# How to scale a web page on an iPhone?

Tags: css, iphone

I have a [simple web page](http://ceving.github.io/ceving/scratch/b2login/b2login.html) showing just a table with some input fields. On a normal browser it is shown in a pretty readable size, because it uses just the browser defaults. But on the iPhone it is rendered extremely small.

[image]

I have no idea why the Safari uses just 20% of the screen and it is quite annoying to zoom the page for every use, because even zooming is painful, because it is hard to hit the headline with a double tap, because it is so small.

Is it possible to use some iOS specific CSS to fix this rendering bug? Or is it possible to tell Safari somehow to start this page in zoomed state?

Comment: You can use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to target just mobile devices.

Comment: Put this meta tag in the head of the HTML <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a meta tag to your html document head to use the device width on mobile devices:

```
<head>
  <title>...</tile>
  ....
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
</head>
```